# WHMCS - Payment gateway with the iframe approach

Tags: php, payment-gateway, whmcs

Hoping someone here who has worked with WHMCS before can assist me.

**Background:**

I'm working on developing a Payment Gateway module for WHMCS which loads the provider's payment page in an iframe.

**The issue:**

WHMCS documentation has this method mentioned, but does not provide any documentation for how this is achieved.

I started here:
https://developers.whmcs.com/payment-gateways/getting-started/

It says:

> ii. iFrame Gateways - Where the gateway payment checkout process is loaded within an iframe. Examples include SagePay Form, Quantum Vault

Based on their documentation here is an example of PHP code, structure only:

```
<?php
function providername_MetaData() {}

function providername_config() {}

function providername_capture($params) {}

function providername_refund($params) {}
?>
```

The above is the Merchant Gateway approach where WHMCS loads the Credit Card form on your website. This approach means you must be PCI compliant.

The provider allows you to use an iframe to circumvent being PCI compliant.

In my research (I did a lot of Googling) and found there is other functions that WHMCS documention does not talk about. Therefore I am unable to work out how it is suppose to work together.

Here's the extra functions:

```
<?php
function paystation_remoteinput($params) {}

function paystation_remoteupdate($params) {}

function paystation_storeremote($params) {}
?>
```

Apparently, you need **_capture** and **_remoteinput** and possibly **_storeremote** functions.

Does anyone have any information on any of these functions that will allow me to understand the process and more importantly how these functions are to work together?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out? i am also looking for ways to make gatewaysample.php be accessable in iframe

Comment: i am also looking for ways to make it show from